# How can I handle the resource expansion while designing/making the transitions in Moqui?

Tags: moqui

I am not able to figure out how should I handle the names of transitions so that it is aligned to the best practices of RESTful API in case of resource expansion.

For instance, if I want to fetch all the orders for a particular customer the URI should be like `https://api.website.com/customers/1000/orders`.

I am able to make the transitions restful for a single resource i.e. customers or orders (as it was demonstrated in the Example App file in Moqui.) but was unable to find any example which will solve the purpose of resource expansion.

The problem that I am facing is while designing the transitions as per the best practices of a restful API. The ExampleApp.xml only has examples for a single resource i.e. Example Entity.

If I take the case of the data model used in HiveMind regarding Project management then the URI should be like this according to the best practices

```
For fetching all Projects- https://api.website.com/projects
For fetching a Milestone for a particular Project - https://api.website.com/projects/DP/milestones/DP-MS-01 (Here, DP is the Project Id)
For fetching a Tasks of a particular Project- https://api.website.com/projects/DP/tasks/DP-1
```

Now if I am designing an API in Moqui framework, this is how I have to name the URIs

```
For fetching all Projects- https://api.website.com/projects
For fetching a Milestone of a Project- https://api.website.com/projects/DP/DP-MS-1
For fetching a Task of a Project- https://api.website.com/projects/DP/DP-1
```

So you can see that these URIs are confusing as I am not able to differentiate between the URI for fetching a milestone or a task.

I can still make the URIs as per the best practices of restful API design by checking the path-parameters (i.e. if tasks is in the path parameter then execute the task related operations and similarly for milestones). But this approach will not be a clean one as its maintenance will become difficult if the parameters in the URIs are too many like `https://api.website.com/projects/DP/milestones/DP-MS-1/tasks/DP-1/worklogs/DP-1-WL-2/party`.

This is just an example scenario in which I want to get the party/person who has added worklog for a task in a particular milestone of a particular project. This is the case of one data model i.e the WorkEffort.

But what about party, customers, orders, products etc. data-models? Designing an API will become an extremely tedious job for the developer of the API.

So I was just asking if there was another cleaner approach that is implemented in Moqui which I could use as reference?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Moqui Framework (not yet released, just available in the GitHub repo though will be part of the next release) there is now an automatic entity REST interface to do find and CrUD operations.

It supports patterns like that described in this question and many others, for some examples see the comments in the rest.xml screen file (that handles the entity REST requests):

https://github.com/moqui/moqui/blob/master/runtime/base-component/webroot/screen/webroot/rest.xml

Answer (score 0):

The concept in Moqui that handles this is path parameters. The easiest examples of it are in the RESTful service examples in the ExampleApp.xml screen:

https://github.com/moqui/moqui/blob/master/runtime/base-component/example/screen/ExampleApp.xml

The example request, in a comment in that screen, with curl looks like:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic am9obi5kb2U6bW9xdWk=" 
    http://localhost:8080/apps/example/ExampleEntity/TEST2
```

The transition that handles this request looks like:

```
<transition name="ExampleEntity" method="get" read-only="true">
    <path-parameter name="exampleId"/>
    <actions>
        <entity-find-one entity-name="Example" value-field="example"/>
        <script>ec.web.sendJsonResponse(example)</script>
    </actions>
    <default-response type="none"/>
</transition>
```

Note the use of the transition.path-parameter element, and that this transition only applies to requests with the HTTP GET method. Everything after the transition location in the URL is treated as a path parameter and put in context fields, like "exampleId" above, in the order of the path-parameter elements.

In your case you would have 2 path parameters, a customer ID and the "orders" string telling it to retrieve orders for the customer.

Comment: There is more complete coverage of this topic in the Making Apps with Moqui book, which you can download from the http://moqui.org site.

Comment: I have referred the ExampleApp.xml but it doesn't contain any examples which will solve the problem that I am facing. Therefore I have edited the question to better explain my problem.